# CORS http response authorization header missing

Tags: cors

I have an existing mvc server that I'm adding restful endpoints to to  test how I could change it to a fully restful backend.

I've created an login endpoint that returns a JWT token as a bearer token in the Authorization header that I've successfully seen returned in my Postman testing. When I use this endpoint (which has a different origin from my backend) in my test web app in Chrome, I am not receiving the Authorization header that includes the bearer token.

I wasn't getting a response at all initially but after some research I discovered CORS and proceeded to add the allow origin response to my http response on the backend:

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:1234");
```

My postman response correctly has the Authorization header:

```
Authorization: "Bearer eyJaslkdas.........
```

But my web app still does not have the header:

```
console.log(response.headers):
{
    content-length: "78"
    content-type: "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1"
}
```

I expected the Jwt bearer token to be in the Authorization header so that I could reuse it on other authenticted requests.

I realised Postman is only a dev tool and does not consider CORS but is there something else I am missing regarding CORS?

Comment: You need to set the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header